# Flutter BLoC authentication

Tags: flutter, mobile, bloc

I am using flutter BLoC for my mobile app but in my `login_form.dart` i have an error

```
return TextField(
          key: const Key('loginForm_emailInput_textField'),
          onChanged: (email) => context.bloc<LoginCubit>().emailChanged(email),
          focusNode: focusNode,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Email',
            helperText: '',
            errorText: state.email.invalid ? 'Invalid Email' : null,
          ),
        );
```

in this `TextField`  area the following :

```
context.bloc<LoginCubit>().emailChanged(email),
```

the `.bloc` shows the following error

```
lib/screens/login/view/login_form.dart:109:44: Error: The method 'bloc' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
     - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../../../Desktop/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'bloc'.
              onChanged: (password) => context.bloc<LoginCubit>().passwordChanged(password),
```

can someone please advise a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
context.bloc<LoginCubit>().emailChanged(email),
```

should be written as

```
context.read<LoginCubit>().emailChanged(email),
```

Answer (score 3):

[context.bloc](https://bloclibrary.dev/?utm_campaign=Flutter%2BDeveloper%2BWeekly&utm_medium=web&utm_source=Flutter_Developer_Weekly_2#/migration?id=%E2%9D%97contextbloc-and-contextrepository-are-deprecated-in-favor-of-contextread-and-contextwatch) has been deprecated.
You can read the example and make necessary changes.

Another way is to use [BlocProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_bloc/latest/flutter_bloc/BlocProvider-class.html)
You can use it like this:

```
BlocProvider.of<BlocName>(context).eventCall()
```

Comment: onChanged: (email) => context.bloc<LoginCubit>().emailChanged(email),

how should it be written? @MaddyB

Comment: Before that, I have one question, is LoginCubit the name of your Bloc Class or is it a cubit used to initialise the bloc? Like, what is the type of LoginCubit?

Comment: If it is your Bloc Class then it can be on hanged: (email) => BlocProvider.of<LoginCubit>(context).email hanged(email)